# Multiple custom keyboards for multiple EditTexts

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have been following Maarten Pennings' great guide on android custom keyboards http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm and can successfully use a custom keyboard to edit one or more EditTexts. My issue comes as I try to use multiple custom keyboards in one Activity. Take Maarten's example of the hexadecimal keyboard, if instead of edittext0, edittext3, and edittext4 all using the custom hexadecimal keyboard, what if i want edittext0 to use the hexadecimal keyboard, edittext3 to use a custom octal keyboard I built, and edittext4 to use a custom duodecimal keyboard. I have tried the following in my MainActivity.java:

```
CustomKeyboard mHexKeyboard;
CustomKeyboard mOctKeybaord;
CustomKeyboard mDuoKeybaord;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mHexKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.hexkeyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
    mOctKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.octkeyboardview, R.xml.octkbd );
    mHexKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.duokeyboardview, R.xml.duokbd );

    mHexKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext0);
    mOctKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext3);
    mKeyboard.registerEditText(R.id.edittext4);
}
```

The error i get is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.username.hexoctduo/com.example.username.hexoctduo.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class android.inputmethodservice.OctKeyboardView
```

It appears my issue is that I am struggling to understand how the XML layout works. Below is my attempt and from the commented out code you can see what else I have tried to do.

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/hex_message"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<EditText android:id="@+id/oct_message"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<EditText android:id="@+id/duo_message"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />


<!--
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/keyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

-->
<android.inputmethodservice.HexKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/hexkeyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.inputmethodservice.OctKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/octkeyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.inputmethodservice.DuoKeyboardView
    android:id="@+id/duokeyboardview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The error is in your layout XML, line 49, not in your code. It cant find the class OctKeyboardView

Comment: You're right, I don't think I totally understand how the android.inputmethodservice tag works, but I have added the layout XML to my post.

Comment: `OctKeyboardView` is not a class in android.inputmethodservice. Is that a custom class you have made? In that case put it in your namespace. Or just use EditText?

Comment: I believe what I am trying to do is use the KeyboardView class in each case. but when I go to construct the custom keyboard if I do:   `(mHexKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.hexkbd );
    mOctKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.octkbd );
    mHexKeyboard= new CustomKeyboard(this, R.id.keyboardview, R.xml.duokbd);`                                                                   It will only display the hex keyboard for all three EditTexts. What do you mean by "Or just use EditText?"

Answer (score 0):

Use the class as `KeyboardView` itself don't use three different structures until and unless you have three classes defined for the same. As in if you have used `HexKeyboardView`, `OctKeyboardView` and `DuoKeyboardView` as the service types the you will have to define three classes for each of them. Instead as you are calling the same constructor to define the CustomKeyboards as in the example at Maarten Penning's. Just place the following structure as a replacement for your xml. I think this should do the trick.

```
        <EditText android:id="@+id/hex_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/oct_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/duo_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/hexkeyboardview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/octkeyboardview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/duokeyboardview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```